# trying to read txt file and converting them into object with different primitive

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader

I am trying to write a method that reads student details from a plain txt file (student id- student name- student surname) using the reader and creates and returns a corresponding new student  object. . The txt file contains details  line by line ex.  student id is on a line and name will be on the next line.

Im trying to do this in the method readStudent()

```
class StudentInputStream{

BufferedReader in;
public StudentInputStream(InputStream input) {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
    }

@Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        in.close();
    }

    public Student readStudent() throws IOException {
        /*Student student1 = new student();*/
        return null; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample of your file and will they be comma separated ?

Comment: STUDENT
100383
JOHN
MITCHELL
STUDENT
100346
AMY
CHING
STUDENT
100373
MICHEAL
SMITH
STUDENT
100389
PAUL
BAKER                                                            there is no comma to separate it, it uses a new line to separate it. the  student  tells me that its a new student and below is the id and then a new line with first name and then new line with surename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is self-explanatory,if you have any questions,please tell me.

```
File file = new File("Your file's path");
     Scanner sc=null;
     try {
        sc = new Scanner(file);
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
     while(sc.hasNextLine()){
         if(sc.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("student")){
             //Assuming each property is in the seperate line of file
         String id,name,surname=null;
         if(sc.hasNextLine()){
         id = sc.nextLine();
         /*if id is int use
          * int id = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
          */
         }
         if(sc.hasNextLine()){
             name = sc.nextLine();
         }
         if(sc.hasNextLine()){
             surname = sc.nextLine();
         }
         list.add(new Student(id,name,surname));
         
         }
     }
```

Using bufferedReader:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("Your file's path");
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
     String str;
     ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
     while((str=br.readLine())!=null){
         if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("student")){
             String id=null,name=null,surname=null;
             if((str=br.readLine())!=null){
             id = str;
             /*if id is int use
              * int id = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
              */
             }
             if((str=br.readLine())!=null){
                 name = str;
             }
             if((str=br.readLine())!=null){
                 surname = str;
             }
             list.add(new Student(id,name,surname));
         }
     }
```

With ObjectInputStream

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("yourfilepath.bin");
     ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
     
     Student s1 = new Student("100383", "JOHN", "MITCHELL");
     Student s2 = new Student("100346", "AMY", "CHING");
     
     
     outputStream.writeObject(s1);
     outputStream.writeObject(s2);
     outputStream.writeObject(null);//to realize that you reach the end of file
     
     outputStream.close();
     out.close();
     
     InputStream in = new FileInputStream("yourfilepath.bin");
     ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(in);
     
     Student temp = null;
     
     while((temp =(Student)inputStream.readObject())!=null){
         System.out.println(temp.id+","+temp.name+","+temp.surname);
     }
```

**OUTPUT**

> 100383,JOHN,MITCHELL
>
> 100346,AMY,CHING

Comment: Thanks for this , will use this if i cant get input stream to work, but is this possible with input stream

Comment: Of course you can do it with inputStream. There are more than one way to manipulate file I/O operations in java like scanner, bufferedReader, inputStream. All do the same thing with different ways and methods. If you wonder how to code it with stream but cannot achieve, let me know, then I will try to help.

Comment: hey, I tried coding it, however it still didn't work. I tried understanding objectinputstream howvever that didnt work too.

Comment: If you are filling the file with objects via ObjectOutputStream,using objectinputstream makes sense. However,if you are filling the file manually, to be able to use readLine(),bufferedReader is more sensible way

Comment: I have added example code of ObjectInputStream just to see how it works.

Comment: Thank you very much it works. Will research into this even more so I can help people who dont understand this too. But again thank you